# Is it possible to specify host when login in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am wondering if it is possible to specify host on the login screen of phpMyAdmin.

Whenever I need to connect to different server, I have to edit the host field in `config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
http://www.onlinehowto.net/config-multiple-servers-in-phpmyadmin/1405

/* Single server config section */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'dbsub';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
```

> Above six lines of code configure PhpMyAdmin to connect to one server. Notice the i > variable that gets increased on the fist line $i++. To define another server just you need to copy paste the block above and change the hostname. It is very important to have the $i++ statement before each databases server configuration. The servers could also be from different database type. For example MySQL and PostgreSQL. This is why PhpMyAdmin is so popular and loved.
>
> Here is working setup in one of the phpmyadmin instances that we manage

```
/*
* Servers configuration
*/
$i = 0;

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'db';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
/*
* Second server
*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'dbsub';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
/*
* Third server
*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'stats1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';

$cfg['DisplayServersList']    = TRUE;

/*
* End of servers configuration
```

> The final change that will make the list of servers show in a nice dropdown list in the login scree is the $cfg[''DisplayServersList''] = TRUE; statement. This way any time you go to the login page of phpmyadmin you will have to select the server you want to work on.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the correct answer is:

```php
$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = true;

/**
 * End of servers configuration
 */
```

Because is ***onetime edit config.inc.php*** and can be specified host on login page as the question say.

Comment: Appreciate and prefer this approach. When you have multiple database servers, you can use a single phpmyadmin instance across them all.

Answer (score 1):

On the root of your PHPMyAdmin you have a file named **config.sample.inc.php**.

Rename it to **config.inc.php** and edit it!

Search for **First server** and on **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']** set for the right value.

```
/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```